# Position points and line

Tags: geometry

At the moment I'm implementing an algorithm to construct a Delaunay triangulation for a set of points. I'm using the algorithm described in Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications. The chapter on Delaunay triangulations is available from this link: http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/

The algorithm defines two special points $p_{-1}$ and $p_{-2}$ as follows:

> In the following, we will say that $p = (x_p , y_p )$ is higher than $q = (x_q , y_q )$ if $y_p > y_q$ or $y_p = y_q$ and $x_q > x_p$ , and use the (lexicographic) ordering on $P$ induced by this relation.
>
> Let $l_{−1}$ be a horizontal line lying below the entire set $P$, and let $l_{−2}$ be a horizontal line lying above $P$. Conceptually, we choose $p_{−1}$ to lie on the line $l_{−1}$ sufficiently far to the right that $p_{−1}$ lies outside every circle defined by three non-collinear points of $P$, and such that the clockwise ordering of the points of $P$ around $p_{−1}$ is identical to their (lexicographic) ordering. Next, we choose $p_{−2}$ to lie on the line $l_{−2}$ sufficiently far to the left that $p_{−2}$ lies outside every circle defined by three non-collinear points of $P \cup \{p_{−1}\}$, and such that the counterclockwise ordering of the points of $P \cup \{p_{−1}\}$ around $p_{−2}$ is identical to their (lexicographic) ordering.

At some point in the algorithm I need to decide if two points lie on the same side of a line. I manage for the most lines, but there is one situation where I don't see the condition: what if the line is determined by two points in $P$ and one or both of the points for which the property needs to be decided is/are special points. I suppose it has to do with the lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clockwise ordering of the points around $p_{-1}$ is identical to the lexicographic ordering. So if $p<q$ then $p_{-1}$ lies on the righthand side of the line from $p$ to $q$. Similar for $p_{-2}$.

Comment: sorry, the site had some Javascript problems that prevented me from voting, accepting and leaving comments.